# Save image from URL to S3 in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, sails.js

I would like to be able to save images from URL to S3. I've been able to do something similar by allowing users to upload profile pictures by using this code ([docs here](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/file-uploads/uploading-to-s-3)):

```
uploadUserImage: function(req, res) {
    var userName = req.params.username;
    var fname = userName + ".jpg";
    var userAvatar = "https://.......;

    req.file('image').upload({
      adapter: require('skipper-s3'),
      key:'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      secret:'xxxxxxxxxx',
      region: "xxxxxx",
      bucket: 'xxxxxxx',
      headers: {
        ACL: 'public-read'
      },
      saveAs: "user-images/"+fname
    }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
```

Is there anyway I could modify this code so I can save images from a URL/ link?

I've been trying to do something like this but I can't figure out how it would work.

```
var request = require('request');
function(person, next) {

      request({
          url:person.image,
          encoding:null
      }, function(err, res, reqBody) {
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
          } else {
              console.log(reqBody);
              console.log(res);
          }
      reqBody.upload({
       adapter: require('skipper-s3'),
       key:'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
       secret:'xxxxxxxxxx',
       region: "xxxxxx",
       bucket: 'xxxxxxx',
       headers: {
        ACL: 'public-read'
      },
        saveAs: "user-images/"+person.id+".jpeg"
      }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
            if(err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                person.image = "https:........";
                return next(null, person);
            }
        });
    });

  },
```

Comment: Got a similar task. Will be happy if you share your solution code as a sample.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible.  You have to download the file yourself, then upload it.

There is only one way to persuade S3 to fetch a file for you and write it to your bucket, and that is when the file is *already* in S3.  S3 can copy a file by fetching from... itself.  But it will **not** go fetch anything `http...` on your behalf.